# How to stop fragments from being recreated in fragment transaction

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an activity with multiple steps, each step being a fragment transaction with an edittext box, with a next/back button to navigate and initiate sending the users input data. I want to be able to move throughout the fragments with the text in each box staying static. I can move back no problem, but as soon as I click next the next fragment is recreated and everything is lost.

I tried:
using a dummy view in onCreateView
refetching the string in onCreate
setRetainInstance(true); in the constructor

Using a viewpager has other complications regarding receiving data which I was not able to solve despite many here attempting to help, so I have no choice but to use fragment transactions in my app.

main/FormActivity.java

```
package com.loopbreakr.formproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class FormActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PageOne.ExitFormInteractionListener{
    //DECLARE COMPONENTS
    private FrameLayout fragmentContainer;
    private Button backToMain;
    private Button startForm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //FIND COMPONENTS IN XML
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);
        fragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
        backToMain = findViewById(R.id.return_button);
        startForm = findViewById(R.id.start_button);

        //SET LISTENERS/INTENTS FOR BUTTONS
        backToMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        startForm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFragments();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openFragments() {
        PageOne fragment1 = PageOne.newInstance();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction beginTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        beginTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        beginTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout,fragment1,"PageOne_tag");
        beginTransaction.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String answerOneText) {

    }
}
```

One of my fragments PageOne.java

```
package com.loopbreakr.formproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class PageOne extends Fragment {

    View restored;
    private static final String SAVED = "text";
    private String savedText;
    private String answerOneString;
    private EditText answerOne;
    private ExitFormInteractionListener mListener;

    public PageOne() {
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public static PageOne newInstance() {
        PageOne fragment = new PageOne();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            savedText = getArguments().getString(SAVED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        if(restored == null){
            restored = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_one, container, false);
        }
        answerOne = restored.findViewById(R.id.answer_one);
        Button exitForm = restored.findViewById(R.id.exit_form);
        Button goNextTwo = restored.findViewById(R.id.gonext_two);

        exitForm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                returnToDesc();
            }
        });
        goNextTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                answerOneString = answerOne.getText().toString();
                sendToTwo(answerOneString);
                openSecondFragment();
            }
        });
        return restored;
    }

    private void sendToTwo(String answerOneText) {
        if(mListener != null){
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(answerOneText);
        }
    }

    private void openSecondFragment() {
        PageTwo fragment2 = PageTwo.newInstance(answerOneString);
        FragmentTransaction fragTransition = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragTransition.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment2,"PageTwo_TAG");
        fragTransition.addToBackStack(null);
        fragTransition.commit();
    }

    private void returnToDesc(){
        FragmentManager fragTransBack = getFragmentManager();
        fragTransBack.popBackStack();
    }
    public interface ExitFormInteractionListener{
        void onFragmentInteraction(String answerOneText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof ExitFormInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (ExitFormInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

}
```

activity_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FormActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_title"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/return_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/return_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/start_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_page_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context=".PageOne"
    android:focusable="true">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/activity_title"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit_form"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/back"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gonext_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/answer_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:hint="@string/answer_one_hint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:minLines="4"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_name"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: i hope i understood the question correctly if yes -> `fragTransBack.popBackStack()` destroys the last fragment in the back stack so that fragment is dead with all of its data, so before it is dead you need to stash the data somewhere , then you can send that data when you recreate it, best option is using one viewmodel for all of your fragments that means attach viewmodel to activity that view model can store all data and will only die with activity, if you don't know about viewmodels then stash data in activity itself or in database maybe.

Comment: Hi, is there any other method to transition back without popping the backstack?

Comment: i don't think so

Comment: all methods of fragmenttransaction https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction  all methods of fragmentmanager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager tell me if find something useful